# How do I recieve and pass "v-" props to children?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to have some set of wrapper components, which mainly purpose, as you might guess, is just to be styled some way and contain passed children/have passed props.

I have wrapper component:

```
// components/FancyButton.vue

<template>
  <button class="fancy-button">
    <slot />
  </button>
</template>
```

How do I pass "v-" props to that `<button>` so it handle click ?

```
// components/App.vue

<template>
  <FancyButton v-on:click="doSomething()"> <!-- props go to nowhere -->
    Some children
  </FancyButton>
</template>

<script>
import FancyButton from './FancyButton'

export default {
  components: {
    FancyButton
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass to the button? The properties of the wrapper component or the onclick function logic?

Comment: Yes, properties of wrapper component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a property to a component, you must declare it as such in the component and then use the `v-bind` syntax when using the component.

For example, if this is your component:

```
<template>
    <button class="fancy-button">
    <slot />
</button>
</template>
```

In the script part of the template:

```
<script>
   module.exports = {

      /...
      props: {
         yourData {
           type: DATA_TYPE
         }
      }
  }
  </script>
```

In the wrapper component, you do the following:

```
<template>
   <FancyButton v-on:click="doSomething()" v-bind:yourData=""> 
        Some children
   </FancyButton>
</template>
```

To pass a function as a props, do this:

```
<script>
   module.exports = {

      /...
      props: {
         yourData {
           type: Function
         }
      }
  }
  </script>
```

This is often times discouraged and you can use events to achieve the same logic that you want.

I recommend reading the following articles:

[How to Pass a Function as a Prop in Vue](https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/)

[Passing functions as props an anti-pattern in Vue.js](https://medium.com/js-dojo/passing-functions-as-props-an-anti-pattern-in-vue-js-b542fc0cf5d)

Comment: I need `v-on:click="doSomething()"` get exactly to child button, not any prop that I can declare in script part (as I understand `props: { 'v-on:click' }` will do nothing). Can I achieve that?

Comment: @felps321- I asked this in my previous comment, to understand your intention. Check my edited answer.

Comment: so what am i doin?

Comment: @felps321 - refer to the edited answer and the links

Comment: oooh, maaan. I got it now. So in vue stuff like that done with events... Okay, cool. Yeah, that's about framework-internal patterns. Thanks

Comment: @felps321 - if my answer helped you, please mark it as such.